# Can OnSelectTemplate returns DataTemplates for multiple CollectionViews? Xamarin.Form C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have 2 CollectionViews in my Xamarin.Form ContentPage, and each one of them has different DataTemplate.
However, the OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container) can only return one DataTemplate which means I can only choose DataTemplates for 1 CollectionView.
Is there anyway to make the OnSelectTemplate returns multiple values or other methods that would fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I fixed this issue by using the code below with the logic that I created, but if anyone has a better solution please still kindly let me know.

The code below is working for me so far with no problem, but I am still looking forward for another solution. Appreciate it in advance!

```
protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject 
container)

    {
        if (CountRunTemplate == 1)
        {
            CountRunTemplate = 2;
            OnSelectTemplate(CountRunTemplate, new MainPage());
            return (isAll == true) ? All1 : Single1;
        }
        else if(CountRunTemplate == 2)
            CountRunTemplate = 1;
        return (isAll == true) ? All2 : Single2;
    }
```